# pandasでindexの値を取り出したい

Tags: python, pandas

pandasで指定した行のindexの取り出し方を知りたいです。

```
      Name               Type
0     blue            Raptors
1    delta            Raptors
2     echo            Raptors
3  charlie            Raptors
4    alpha  Tyrannosaurus rex
```

このようなデータがあった場合に、Nameでソートをした後に、上から順にindexの値を取り出したいのですが、調べてもどうすればよいのかがわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
Name,Type
blue,Raptors
delta,Raptors
echo,Raptors
charlie,Raptors
alpha,Tyrannosaurus rex
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
idx = df.sort_values('Name').index.to_list()

print(idx)
#
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
```